# How to block some countries in OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using OCI for Wireguard Server to prevent my IP from being leaked
because I run the game server(Rust)

However, due to frequent network attacks recently, I would like to block some countries
What should I do?
I don't want to use something like iptables.

I've contacted Oracle, but they keep telling me to use WAF.